# SharePoint 2013 Active Directory FBA Change Password solutions

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, active-directory, forms-authentication, password

I have a SharePoint 2013 set up using mix mode authentication. Windows authentication for internal users, and Forms Based Authentication using an LDAP provider against Active Directory for external users.
Internal users don't need the functionality, because they are directly connected with AD anyway, only external FBA users need it.

I need a way for external FBA users to change their active directory passwords. ITaCS Change Password worked for SharePoint 2010, but I've been trying to find a solution for 2013 and have come up with nothing.

1. [This example from codeplex](http://changepassword.codeplex.com/) works, but only for SP 2010
2. [SharePoint 2013 FBA Pack](http://sharepoint2013fba.codeplex.com/) works for SQL Membership in 2013
3. [This example from code plex](http://changepasswordfromsharepoint2013.codeplex.com/) works only for Windows Authentication for 2013
4. [This password reset webpart from bamboo solutions](http://store.bamboosolutions.com/sharepoint-password-reset-web-part.aspx) looks like it will work, but I would prefer to avoid spending the money of at all possible.

Does anyone know where I can either find a ready built solution, or some guidance on how to create one?

Answer (score 1):

By your trails it is safe to say that you are ok with Custom Code.
If so why not do it using regular C# code & tap into the AD.
Follow below thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066131/how-to-programmatically-change-active-directory-password